# Angular - How to Project $http Response

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I want to project the result of my $http call into another model in order to make the projection global to the service call.

In other words, the result i get from my http/api call is not using the exact model i want.

How do i do this projection within my service class?

```
angular.module('openart')
.factory('BritishLibraryApi', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        getPage:function(page){
            return $http({method:"GET",url:'/api/british-library/'+page})
                .success(function(data){
                    //would like to do something here like
                    return data.results.map(function(i){

                        //project i into another model here
                        return {

                        };
                    });
                });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: You could put in your service an other service with a setter/getter and getByPageId

Comment: How do you plan to bind to the `$scope` in the controller?  Do you want to return a promise here?

Answer (score 0):

If you create your own promise and resolve to your mapped data

```
angular.module('openart')
.factory('BritishLibraryApi', ['$http','$q', function ($http,$q) {
    return {
        getPage:function(page){
            var defer=$q.defer();
            $http({method:"GET",url:'/api/british-library/'+page})
                .success(function(data){
                    //would like to do something here like
                    defer.resolve(data.results.map(function(i){

                        //project i into another model here
                        return {
                        };
                    }));
                });
            return defer.promise;
        }
    };
}]);
```